# How to setup Glew and Glut in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012

By reading question you would get the idea about description.

Steps I done so far:

1. download glut from internet
2. copy `glut.dll` to windowsvow64 (I'm using x64).
3. Copy glut header files  to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\GL`
4. Copy `glut.lib` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib`

and done the same for glew and glfw. I edited additional libraries (glew.lib; glut.lib; etc)

But so far, its not compiling a simple program mentioned in [this website](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-12-opengl-extensions/).

Here are the errors

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main
```

(and many more are like this)

Comment: Did you added a references to .dlls?

Comment: I did copy pate .dll into windowsvow64 of windows folder. Can you explain what kind of reference you are talking about?
Double Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be slightly off-topic but I would advise downloading freeglut instead of glut from http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/ .freeglut is more active in terms of its development and is recommended in most GL textbooks

Answer (score 1):

**To add a reference in Visual Basic**
In **Solution Explorer**, double-click the **My Project** node for the project.
In the **Project Designer**, click the **References tab**.
Click the **Add button** to open the **Add Reference** dialog box.
In the **Add Reference** dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
Select the components you want to reference, and then click **OK**.

**To add a reference in Visual C#**
In **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project node and click **Add Reference**.
In the **Add Reference dialog** box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
Select the components you want to reference, and then click **OK**.

**To add a reference in Visual C++**
In **Solution Explorer**, select the project.
On the **Project menu**, click **Add References**.

Note In Visual C++ 2005, click **References** on the Project menu, and then click **Add New Reference**.
In the **Add References dialog box**, click the tab that corresponds with the category that you want to add a reference to.

Note In Visual C++ 2005, click the **Browse** tab in the Add References dialog box.
Click **Browse**, locate the component that you want on your local drive, and then click **OK**. The component is added to the **Selected Components** field.

Note In Visual C++ 2005, locate the component that you want on your local drive.
To add the selected reference to the current tab, click Add.

Note In Visual C++ 2005, click OK to close the dialog box and add the component in the References list box on the Properties Page dialog box of the project.

More about this you can find [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Hey Hoh! I hope you are doing fine. I need this in C++. Is there any solution for doing this ? at all ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add your dll's to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin**

If you have the includes and libs in the directories above then that should be fine.

Now **right click** on your **project** and select **Properties**

Go to **linker** and within this, select **Input**

make sure you have listed the required libraries in here like your glew.lib, freeglut.lib and the following which is recommended on the glfw website:

glfw3.lib, opengl32.lib (I'm assuming you're using **glfw3**)

See here for more info:

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the libraries for example glut.lib and the others to the project, The compiler cannot scan all libraries looking for the functions you are invoking; only does that for the standard library. So in VS from the project Menu select properties, then for the linker input add the libraries you are using to additional dependencies.

Comment: Hi, hisham
Well I did copy paste the .lib files into VC's lib folder. And I did write in additional dependencies (glut.lib etc). But nothing is working so far.